# Zoom problem in 3D using C# with DirectX

Tags: c#, directx, using

Zoom a give object in windows form application using c#.net with directx.
what can I do, pls help me.

Comment: No, need to cry in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Download:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9ac86eca-206f-4274-97f2-ef6c8b1f478f

Start reading & experimenting with the samples.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale the 3D object. Multiply the object by a scale matrix  (e.g. Matrix.CreateScale(...))